# Adding multiple markers to map in open layers v4.2

Tags: openlayers

I imported a dataset of csv format using function d3.csv. The dataset contains lat and long fields. I tried adding the markers to the map by iterating through the dataset

```
d3.csv("xyz.csv", function(data) {
data.forEach( function(d) {

var pos = ol.proj.fromLonLat([d.longitude, d.latitude]);     
      var marker = new ol.Overlay({
        position: pos,
        positioning: 'center-center',
        element: document.getElementById('marker'),
        stopEvent: false
      });
      map.addOverlay(marker);
}
);
```

But could not make it. Do I have to use addFeature for this ?

Comment: element is always same as `document.getElementById('marker')` in your code. which means, markers will be over-written to the same div.  you should change it for each marker.

Comment: It would probably be more efficient to populate an ol.source.Vector with your data, and render it with an ol.layer.Vector.